# Spring- How to remove a property from a list of Objects?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, collections

I have an Entity "Person" which has following properties,

```
Id
Name
F-Name
Age
Address
```

When I call a repository function findAll() on Person, it returns a list of Persons.

```
List<Person> list = somefuntionToConvertIterableToList(personRepository.findAll());
```

this list has multiple objects of Person Type.

Person ...... Id1,Name1, F-Name1, Age1, Address1

Person .......IdN,NameN, F-NameN, AgeN, AddressN

I need to remove "Id" from all Persons, what should I do?

I know we can use "remove" to delete an element of list, but how to delete a property with in an element?

Comment: Please explain why do you want to do that?

Comment: I need to pass this data to ResponseEntity to client, and obviously "Id" is of no use to client.

Comment: Why don't you create a DTO for the purpose?

Comment: You can't 'delete' a property! Return a customized view of the data using a DTO or similar such as Spring data Projections https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections or JsonView https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation

Comment: if its outgoing maybe jacksons @JsonIgnore helps. if its internal create an additional class which has all attributes but the id and construct it from person.

Comment: @RichieK i had tried to use 

   '@JsonIgnore' but it was of no use... I did this 
     '@JsonIgnore'
     private Long id;

but still getting Id in result.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need used : @JsonIgnore in Id look like:

```
@JsonIgnore
   Field you want remove in reponse.
```

Or you can create DTO and put all field you want return look like :

```
  public class PersonDTO {
      //all field you want return
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can of course set `id` null or add ignores in serialization but maybe you do not want to load `id` at all. Usually you then would use `DTO` or `Tuple` to decide what fields to populate. So not first to populate all and then remove unneeded (I have not used your `Person` but just one simplified example class).

Tuple query in your repository would simply be like (JPQL):

```
@Query("SELECT te.name AS name, te.created as created FROM TestEntity te")
List<Tuple> findAllTuple();
```

This would need then do extra work to have tuple to correspond original entity when serialized. So preferably with a `DTO`, like:

```
// This class would be exactly as your Person but without that id
@AllArgsConstructor // you need the constructor for new in jpql
public class TestEntityDto {
    private String name;
    private LocalDateTime created;
}
```

while the query in your repository would be like:

```
@Query("SELECT NEW org.example.data.entity.dto.TestEntityDto(te.name, te.created) FROM TestEntity te")
List<TestEntityDto> findAllDto();
```