# Why the Spring's @Query annotation returns Object type?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have the below query to fetch specific columns of a entity/table from database

```
@Query("SELECT u.email, u.password FROM User u WHERE email = :email")
Optional<User> getCredentialsByEmail( @Param("email") String email);
```

But this gives the `ClassCastException`, and that's because the query return the `Object` type instead of `User`.

Whereas, if I select all the columns as below:

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE email = :email")
Optional<User> getCredentialsByEmail( @Param("email") String email);
```

the query return the correct class type i.e `User`. I don't understand why this difference is provided by the Spring framework.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: you may get answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007341/spring-jpa-selecting-specific-columns

Answer (score 2):

If you required only couple of columns the you can use `Object[]` object array

```
@Query("SELECT u.email, u.password FROM User u WHERE email = :email")
Optional<Object[]> getCredentialsByEmail( @Param("email") String email);
```

From `0` position you can get the `email`

From `1` position you can get the `password`

If you like to make it much clear, use `Interface`

```
public interface Response {

 public String getEmail();

 public String getPAssword();

}
```

**Query** make sure column names and `get` names should match, if not you can use `allies` in query

```
@Query("SELECT u.email, u.password FROM User u WHERE email = :email")
Optional<Response> getCredentialsByEmail( @Param("email") String email);
```

Answer (score 1):

As commented your first query does not return `User` object but a `Tuple` containing the selected columns. `Tuple` is not necessarily tied to any specific entity but just a set of columns your query returns.

There are at least following options how you can handle this:

- make your repo method return a tuple object
- make a DTO for selected columns and instantiate it with `new` operator
- with `new` operator make a constructor for your user object that takes selected columns

The last option would be like creating a constructor:

```
public User(String email, String password ) {
    // set the field values
}
```

and query like:

```
@Query("SELECT NEW some.package.User(u.email u.password) FROM USER u WHERE email = :email")
```

For more details see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54462971/6413377)

Comment: I cannot use DTOs in the persistence layer. They are all created in Web layer for some reasons. Isn't there any other way(not `Tuple`)?

Comment: @TheCoder see the last option I wrote, creatign `User` with `new` operator with a specific constructor. I'll edit the answer a bit.